# We query the messages API a lot, but after a while it becomes inconsistent

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, sharepointframework

We are using graph messages queries a lot in a sharepoint app of ours. Mail get tagged using extended properties and users are treating them using the sharepoint app.

We are accordingly requesting the graph API constantly even though we cache some of the information.

The app and the querying work superb, but after a short while (let's say 30 minutes) it starts to misbehave. It hangs, becomes slow and sometimes we have a timeout.

Users do have their app open at all times and we do refresh tokens using adal and all that (old school nowadays, I know)

Is there a correlation of performance or some kind of throttling going on inside exchange online, graph or sharepoint that can be the reason behind this?

Links, experiences or solutions are appreciated;)

Best regards
Ole

Comment: Did you read  and understand the throttling policy?

Comment: Are you getting `HTTP 429` responses?

Comment: thanx @ilansch , do you mean the throttling guidance for graph?